# Trying to make a chessboard that takes simple string inputs and stores them in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am still new to Java and have been working with 2D arrays recently. What I am trying to do is make a simple 2D grid array of a Chessboard that has the arrays from a1 all the way to h8. The first thing I tried to do is convert the array [8][8] so that the first 8 was characters and the second 8 was integers. What I am currently trying to do is prompt the user and ask them which coordinate they would like to choose (from a1 all the way to h8). When they choose one of the coordinates, I would like them to enter a string (which in the future will be my chess pieces) that will be stored on the board, so that, when I use another class to print these strings, it'll give me an output like "a5 - Lemon (As im not checking to see if the chess piece is a valid piece yet) or "h2 - Queen".
So, to clarify, the program asks the user "Please enter a coordinate (e.g. a5)". "Now, Please enter a piece to be placed on that coordinate" Which then gets stored in that coordinate. When the user types, for example, "Done" I would like all the coordinates that have pieces on them to be revealed as well as what piece was put on them.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChessBoard
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] grid = new int [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(rows + "" + (col + 1) + " ");
                
            }

            String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
            boolean validCoordinate = false;   // will be true if position is valid
            while ( ! validCoordinate) {
               System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
               input = scanner.next();
               validCoordinate = input.matches("[a-g][1-8]"); 
            };
            // now we now that the input is valid
            int col = (int)(input.charAt(0) - 'a'); 
            int row = (int)(input.charAt(1) - '0'); 
        }
    }

}
```

I have used a while loop to continuously prompt the user until they give a correct coordinate, but Im not sure how to prompt the user to enter a piece that gets stored in that coordinate?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to store the piece name with the coordinates, you will need a 2D array of strings instead of integers.

After changing that, you take the user input again and then save the coordinates with the piece and save it in the 2d array at said  column and row.

Also, the row is retrieved from the character (a-b-c-etc..) and the column from the number and not the way around.

```
public class ChessBoard
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] grid = new String [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(rows + "" + (col + 1) + " ");

            }

            String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
            boolean validCoordinate = false;   // will be true if position is valid
            while ( ! validCoordinate) {
                System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
                input = scanner.next();
                validCoordinate = input.matches("[a-g][1-8]");
            };
            // now we now that the input is valid
            int row = input.charAt(0) - 'a';
            int col = input.charAt(1) - '1';
            String temp = input + " - ";
            System.out.println("Insert your piece:");
            input = scanner.next();
            grid[row][col] = temp + input;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I get one compiler error at the very end System.out.println because Arrays isn't declared I think? What should I replace it with?

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;` above your class

Comment: Ah, I've come across another problem which I think was to do with my code originally. Each time it goes through asking the user for inputs, it goes to the next column, so first it'll ask the user for a coordinate in a1-8, then b1-8 and so forth until it reaches h1-8, and after that it'll just keep asking the user for a piece rather than what coordinate they want to place that piece on. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited the answer, so now I am saving the coordinates in another array then iterating over it in order for the user to enter the piece name for each coordinate.

Comment: I tried this but now everytime the user enters a coordinate, it goes to the next row of coordinates without asking the user for the piece they want to input. So, my desired output is: "Enter a coordinate: " "Enter a piece: " The value then gets stored in that coordinate and the program keeps asking the user for coordinates and pieces until the user says "Done" or something

Comment: What was the problem with the previous code? you will first ask the user to put the coordinates and after that set the piece to this coordinate which is exactly what you wanted unless I missed something?

Comment: Recheck the code now, you will set for example a1 then "Queen" then b2 then "King" etc..

Comment: perfect, now I just need to add a "done" to which will use a new class to print the array, thanks!